# The “Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10” option not available - I have 4 partitions and unused unallocated space

Tags: dual-boot, disk-usage

I am trying hard to install Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop, alongside Windows 10. I created an extra partition via shrinking, it's around 70 GB. I have the USB with the installation kit, but when I reboot my system, I have no option to install alongside Windows 10.

When I install, after setting the keyboard and WiFi access, I always run into a  message like there's only 4 GB space available and the minimum is 8.3 GB. (Actually I want to use the 75 GB partition - but I am not able to find or select it.) I have read quite a few posts here and on youtube, but nothing seems to be helping. The problem is that I have no options during installation, not even "Something else", just run Ubuntu in-memory, and when trying to install, it is not able to finalize due to lack of space mentioned above.

When installing I run sudo parted -l. It shows the 4gb USB drive but nothing else.

**Status Now**, I have the 68 GB unallocated space, removed the NTFS formatting of it. But, in total I already have 4 primary partitions in my 480 GB SSD, two of which are system partitions. I checked, my SSD is GPT not MBR.
See latest picture.
[List of partitions.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1T9i1RuQQOiPL3xzToqWxE-JcL2SFOTI3)
Installation still not working, same issue.
*What can I do to overcome this error message and finalize installation?*

Comment: If you have a legacy/dos/mbr partitioned HDD/SSD, it doesn't matter how much space you have available if you already have 4 primary partitions; that's the maximum allowed in the partition table. You haven't said what type of partition table you are using, nor how many primary slots (of the 4) are already used.  Did you create a partition in the space 70gb of space? what type? or leave it as empty space available for Ubuntu to install into?  If it was space, what type of partition table is used and any free slots available?

Comment: I have 3 partitions on my 480 GB SSD. I want to use E:  which will be totally dedicated to the new linux installation (it's around 70 GB). If you check the screenshot, you can see: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Va-6S4hqWnSfQA6iHllCv2Ea3ecoAPs6 I want to use E: for Ubuntu. F: is the USB drive with the installation package. I am not aware what kind of partitions I have , if it is DOS or not. I think it's NTFS.

Comment: see if the partition is there using gparted

Comment: You cannot use NTFS partition for Linux, it normally is ext4 or one of many other supported formats. Post this above in your question to preserve format: `sudo parted -l`  If Windows 10, you must have fast start up off. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: Even without NTFS only with the empty partition it didn't work.

Comment: Your disk has gpt parttiioning, because your first picture had five primary partitions -- good.  You didn't post the requested sudo parted -l , so guessing here, you removed the ntfs filesystem from the fifth partition, but ragardless of what Microsoft then labels that space, the Ubuntu installer will not just grab an empty partition, you would need to use the "Something else" choice, and indicate that the partition needs an ext4 filesystem and to be used as root (/).  Or, delete the partition, create unused-unpartitioned space on the disk,  and the Ubuntu installer should use that.

Comment: 'Something else ' choice was not available.

Comment: What brand/model system? What video card/chip? Is Windows fast startup  or hibernation off? Have you updated UEFI for system? And if SSD updated firmware for SSD? http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation
also:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi